# date format in PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that works fine in Mysql

$date

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));
```

var_dump of $date and $imdb_id

```
string '2013-06-04' (length=10)
string '2244871' (length=7)
```

prepare

```
SELECT * FROM show_episode, show_episode_airdate, show_network, shows 
WHERE show_episode.imdb_id_show = :imdb_id 
AND show_episode.episode_id = show_episode_airdate.episode_id 
AND show_network.show_id = shows.id 
AND shows.imdb_id = show_episode.imdb_id_show 
AND show_episode_airdate.airdate >= :date 
ORDER BY show_episode_airdate.airdate ASC LIMIT 3
```

Here's the PHP:

```
$checkunaired = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM show_episode, show_episode_airdate, show_network, shows WHERE show_episode.imdb_id_show = :imdb_id AND show_episode.episode_id = show_episode_airdate.episode_id AND show_network.show_id = shows.id AND shows.imdb_id = show_episode.imdb_id_show AND show_episode_airdate.airdate >= :date ORDER BY show_episode_airdate.airdate ASC LIMIT 3');
$checkunaired->execute(array(':imdb_id' => $imdb_id, ':date' => $date));
```

:date being $date with the format 'Y-m-d' and show_episode_airdate.airdate being a column with dates formatted 'Y-m-d' (though I'm not sure Mysql knows they are dates ?)

When I try the query in phpmyadmin with '2013-06-04' instead of :date, it returns what I want but it seems to ignore the date parameter when I use it in my code?

Does anyone know why ?

Edit:

```
  $unairedepisodessql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM show_episode, show_episode_airdate, show_network WHERE show_episode.imdb_id_show = :imdb_id AND show_network.show_id = :show_id AND show_episode.episode_id = show_episode_airdate.episode_id AND show_episode_airdate.airdate >= :date LIMIT 3');
                        $erro = $unairedepisodessql->errorCode();
                        var_dump($erro);
```

returns null

Comment: where are `$imdb_id` and `$date` defined?

Comment: You haven't configured PHP/PDO to report errors or `$date` does not contain `'2013-06-04'`. There's no way to tell from your question.

Comment: Dump the two variables in question and check whether they *actually* contain what you think they do.

Comment: I added var_dump and how I defined $date

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario The query does not return any errors, it just seems to ignore or possibly think it did what I wanted it to do with the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first; you can do the same query efficiently using MySQL's join statements:

```
SELECT se.*, s.*, sea.*, sn.*
FROM show_episode se
INNER JOIN show_episode_airdate sea
    ON se.episode_id = sea.episode_id 
INNER JOIN show_network sn, shows s   ## This part might be a bit wrong....
    ON ( s.imdb_id = se.imdb_id_show 
        AND sn.show_id = s.id )
WHERE se.imdb_id_show = :imdb_id 
    AND sea.airdate >= :date 
ORDER BY sea.airdate ASC 
LIMIT 3
```

Now, to the question at hand.

Are you sure that your column `airdate` has the MySQL's `DATE` data type? You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE show_episode_airdate` to find out.

Does the `$date` variable in PHP also has the string `'2013-06-04'`? How are you setting this value? There might be a chance that you were using wrong parameters if it was generated using `date()`.

Comment: $date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));
and sea.airdate does have a date type

Comment: Ok, @metareviewr try using `date('Y-m-d')` only. With no other arguments.